# Forge Viewer - how to save/load settings of ViewCubeUI

Tags: autodesk-forge

ViewCubeUI extension allows setting up home-view, front-view and top-view. Is there a way to extract that settings in JavaScript code, and to reload it into ViewCubeUI next time?

Alternatively, is there a way to set home-view, front-view and top-view in ViewCubeUI using 'state' obtained from viewer.getState function?

Thank you

Bandu

Answer (score 1):

Thanks to Michael Beale, I implemented a solution. `viewer.autocam.setHomeViewFrom()` allows programmatically setting up ViewerCube. To gather current viewport, can use `viewer.autocam.getCurrentView()`. If you happen to stringily it (to save) and parse it (to load), remember to replace {x: x, y: y, z: z} structures with THREE.Vector3 objects before calling setHomeViewerFrom function.